# CURL: How to send a file as part of a json encoded payload

Tags: curl

I'm trying to use [this Replicate API](https://replicate.com/jingyunliang/swinir). On that page it says to access the API with:

```
curl -s -X POST \
  -d '{"version": "9d91795e944f3a585fa83f749617fc75821bea8b323348f39cf84f8fd0cbc2f7", "input": {"image": "..."}}' \
  -H "Authorization: Token $REPLICATE_API_TOKEN" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions
```

Here's my question: what goes in `"..."`? It can't be a local file path because that's inside a json encoded string, and it can't be the file data because the receiver wouldn't know the file format. How to use this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a URL to the image

```
curl http://localhost:5000/predictions -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"input": {
    "image": "https://url/to/file",
    "task_type": "Real-World Image Super-Resolution-Large",
    "noise": "15",
    "jpeg": "40"
  }}'
```

Or a data URL

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>

 "data:image/jpg;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMAJH/AOQAE////wAxAGUAdywAAAAADAAMAAACFISPqQsRbBxsT7l7EcZLQs+A05gUADs="
```